# Title Service on Angular 5 with SSR

Tags: angular, angular-universal

Checking Angular Universal project I found that they state the following:

**Support Title and Meta services on the server** ([you can check that here](https://github.com/angular/universal#completed)).

But the truth is, I can't find how to implement this on the server. I checked in `@angular/platform-server` and couldn't fine the Title service.

Any idea how to do this?

**NOTE: I can make it work using the Title serivce in the browser. The problem is the server rendering**

**EDIT: setTitle works fine. The issue was coming form an incorrect usage of a subscription in the server**

[image]

Comment: I think it means that you just use these 2 services on the browser app as normal and that they'll appear correctly when the page is rendered server side. I've done that and it works as expected

Comment: I'm using the Title service, and works fine client side, but the rendered page doesn't have the expected title, the title changes once the Angular app is loaded

Comment: What's the initial title when the page is rendered (the one you see in source view)? Is it the one set in index.html?

Comment: Exactly, I just see the one in the index.html

Comment: And is the content correctly rendered server side? Apart from title and meta

Comment: Exactly, everything ok, once I arrive home I'll share the code

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error wasn't in the section that I asked for. The error comes from a side effect functionality in the code.

Comment: @nicowernli hi i'm facing the same issue. any change you can assist?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, they are right, it's not in `'@angular/platform-server'` but in `'@angular/platform-browser'`

Just create a service import this line

```
import { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Pass in constructor Like

```
constructor(
    private meta : Meta, 
    private title : Title
){
```

Now you can create meta tags and title just create a method like below and use it wherever you want

```
addMetaTags(title, description) {
    //console.log(title, description);

    this.title.setTitle(title);

    this.addTag('description', description);
}
addTag(name, content) {
    //console.log(name, content);
    this.meta.addTags([{
        name: name,
        content: content
    }]);
}
```

You can also create og: tags for social media and other different type of metas just from about method.
Ex:-

```
addOgTags(title, type, url, description, image, width, height){
        if(title){
            this.addPropertyTag('og:title', title);
        }
        if(description){
            this.addPropertyTag('og:description', description);
        }
        if(url){
            this.addPropertyTag('og:url', this.domain + url);
        }
        if(image){
            this.addPropertyTag('og:image', image);
            this.addPropertyTag('og:image:url', image);
        }
        if(type){
            this.addPropertyTag('og:type', type);
        }
        if(width){
            this.addPropertyTag('og:image:width', width);
        }
        if(height){
            this.addPropertyTag('og:image:height', height);
        }
    }
    addTwitterTags(card, title, description, image){
        //console.log(card, title, description, image);
        if(card){
            this.addTag('twitter:card', card);
        }
        if(title){
            this.addTag('twitter:title', title);
        }
        if(description){
            this.addTag('twitter:description', description);
        }
        if(image){
            this.addTag('twitter:image:src', image);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for the answer, but as I said in the comments of my question, I know how the service work, and it works fine on browser, but is useless if doesn't work on server, and thats my problem, the rendered HTML from the server is not changing, is changing later on in the client

Comment: mate, why don't you use it and press ctrl+u and see in view source if you can see the meta tags, if you can, bingo it's working

Comment: most people make the mistake here is that this code should run while server side rendering, means when `if(!this.isBrowser){ //here }}`

Comment: thats exactly what is not happening

Comment: one you have unsuffiecient info in your question, give me your code, upload it on github, then I can help or follow this github repo https://github.com/angular/universal-starter

Comment: The error is in another piece of the app, incorrect usage of a subscription in the server. Thanks for you help @Rakeschand, I'm going to close this question

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood how angular universal works. From the screenshot you provided, it looks like you are expecting the metadata to be set "server side" for the http://localhost:4200 server. However, this server is probably your front server, served by ng serve or other.

To see the meta being set server side, you need to navigate to the url of the backend universal server (nodejs or asp.net core).

In the sample repo [here](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter), it is for instance port 4000 on the server where universal is running.

Once it's working, in production you will typically have a proxy server (nginx or other) on port 80 that transfers the request to your angular universal (nodejs or asp.net core, on port 4000 or whatever, not accessible from the outside), which  in turn will do the server side rendering with correct meta

Comment: That server is running an expressjs sever. I had two tabs to show the difference between what is rendered and what is happening on the client

Comment: can you add in your question the code for your angular universal server?

Comment: I found the error and is in another place, the setTitle works now. Thanks for your help